# Where is it Possible to Find DTED0 Set?

Tags: data, dem, dted

As I understand, DTED0 should be available for free. Yet, I am not able to find any download link. Everything that Google search brings up (eg. http://geoengine.nima.mil) is dead and not working.

Comment: Are you looking for GTOPO30?

Comment: @Vice, I read a bit about it, it uses USGS DEM format so that is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The military format specification (MIL-PRF-89020B) for the Digital Terrain Elevation Data (DTED) is available in a multitude of locations, including the [NGA reference site](http://earth-info.nga.mil/publications/specs/printed/89020B/89020B.pdf) and at the [USGS](http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/Documentation/MIL-PDF-89020B.pdf) (which publishes some [SRTM](http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/) data in DTED format).

The DTED Level 0 data is relatively small, and is often published as a concatenation of large area or global tiles (in other than DTED format, at the 30 arc-second resolution specified for mid-latitude locations) in products like [GMTED2010](https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/GMTED2010).

There isn't much gain to reading the format natively if your sole goal is access to Level 0 data, since you can use it in a much more portable form (16-bit [TIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format)), and much of the work of mosaicking will already have been done for you.

Answer (score 3):

DTED is the name of a data format. As mentionned by @Vince, it is also used as a data name (I didn't know that) but most of the time it is associated with SRTM data.

If you are looking for free DEM, use the SRTM DTED1(see [cgiar](http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SELECTION/inputCoord.asp) or on [earthexplorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/)). It is DTED1 (not 0) but higher spatial resolution is often useful. For low resolution you also have [GMTED2010](https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/GMTED2010) (better than GTOPO30, and based on DTED0 along with other datasets)

EDIT : DTED0 seems to be available [here](http://data.geocomm.com/catalog/), but you'll need to register (I have not tested)

Comment: Thank you. As far as I understand, DTED0 and DTED1 are different formats. I want to see an example of how the DTED0 format is represented: directory structure, which files and headers it contains etc.

Comment: DTED is the milspec *and* the data in that format published by NGA. DTED Level 0 and DTED Level 1 files are in the same format (albeit at different post spacings), as published in the MIL-PRF-89020B document.  If you want the format specification, you should edit the question to state this.

Answer (score 2):

DTED (or Digital Terrain Elevation Data) is a standard of digital datasets which consists of a matrix of terrain elevation values, i.e., a Digital Elevation Model. 
The DTED format for level 0, 1 and 2 is described in U.S. Military Specification Digital Terrain Elevation Data (DTED) MIL-PRF-89020B, and amongst other parameters describes the resolution for each level:
Level 0 has a post spacing of approximately 900 meters.
Level 1 has a post spacing of approximately 90 meters.
Level 2 has a post spacing of approximately 30 meters